# Entity Framework adding record into many to many mapping table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 3 tables,

1) Customer (Id, Name, bla bla)

2) CustomerGroups (GroupId, GroupName)

3) CustomerInGroups (CustomerId, GroupId)

```
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{                
    context.Customers.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return entity.Id;
}
```

How do I add a record into CustomerInGroups? EntityFramework doesn't generate entities for such many-to-many mapping tables

Edit:

Both the Id columns in Customer and CustomerGroups are set to auto increment.

So in my CustomersGroup table, I have

```
Id          Name
----------------------------
1           Normal
2           VIP
```

I tried doing this as one of the posters suggested:

```
entity.CustomerGroups = new List<CustomerGroup>
{
    new CustomerGroup {Id = 2 }
};
context.Customers.Add(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
return entity.Id;
```

However, when I did this, instead of creating a record in the mapping table like this:

```
CustomerId          GroupId
----------------------------
1                   2
```

What I got was

```
CustomerInGroups
    CustomerId          GroupId
    ----------------------------
    1                   3

CustomerGroups
    Id          Name
    ----------------------------
    1           Normal
    2           VIP
    3           NULL
```

It actually created another entry in my CustomerGroups table, which is not what I want

Comment: Is entity framework not automatically updating the join table for you when you assign a customer to a group or vice versa? You don't need to create a separate entity if the join doesn't have payload (ie a join that is _only_ foreign keys)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flying a little blind since you didn't include what properties `entity` has. But you should have a property for the relationship to `CustomerGroups`. Just set that property with the groups you want to be related to. For example, this would create a new Group name "foo bar" and relate the entity to that group.

```
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{
    entity.CustomerGroups = new List<CustomerGroup> { GroupName = "Foo bar" };
    context.Customers.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return entity.Id;
}
```

If the relationship is setup correctly, EF will automatically insert a record into `CustomerGroups` and insert a relationship into the `CustomerInGroups` table.

EDIT:

If you're trying to add an existing `CustomerGroup` to a new Customer. You'll want to get the `CustomerGroup` from the database first, then add it to the Customer entity you're inserting.

```
using (var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{
    var customerGroups = context.CustomerGroups.Where(...).ToList(); // get your CustomerGroup object(s) here, and ensure it's enumerated with ToList()
    entity.CustomerGroups = customerGroups;
    context.Customers.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return entity.Id;
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It created another record in my groups table

Comment: @PapyrusBit Edited my answer to allow for a `CustomerGroup` to be created already. So you can relate to an already existing `CustomerGroup` from a customer.

Comment: @StevenV Even though I followed what you are doing when the 2nd entity exists, it is still creating a new record for me :(

Comment: @Ciwan You may want to post a new question your details, and point to this answer as a reference point. I think you'll be better served by the community.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to assing an *existing* customer to an _existing group and assuming that the CustomerGroup object exposes an ICollection do the following:

```
(var context = DataObjectFactory.CreateContext())
{
    context.Customers.Add(entity);
    var group = context.CustomerGroups.Find(2); // or however you retrieve the existing group
    group.Customers.Add(entity);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return entity.Id
}
```

The Find() method is Entity Framework Code First (DbContext) way of finding by Id. I can't remember of the top of my head the "proper" ObjectContext way of doing it but but .Single(g => g.Id == 2) would also work.

Ideally you'd give us a better idea of how your entities are mapped so we know how you are relating your entities.

Comment: I'm doing all the above, but it is still creating a new record in the database! Even though I am telling it to use an existing record and form a relationship between the new entity and the new record!

Comment: @Ciwan did you post a new question? It's hard to answer just based on your comment. As a guide make sure you aren't adding any existing entity back to any EF context collections.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Steven-v's answer, If you previously fetched customer groups and you don't want to fetch them again from db, you also can just attach them to the context.

```
foreach (var c in customer.CustomerGroups)
{
     _db.CustomerGroups.Attach(c);
}        
_db.Customer.Add(customer);
_db.SaveChanges();
```