# EF Inserting Duplicate Records in Many to Many tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am quite confused on this one.

I have read many articles such as:

[Entity Framework adding record into many to many mapping table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262974/entity-framework-adding-record-into-many-to-many-mapping-table)

and my situation matches what is described in these articles. In essence I have a typical many to many scenario. I have a customer table, a fixed address table, and CustomerFixedAddress. As you might guess the CustomerFixedAddress table is two columns. The CustomerId and the FixedAddressId.

Just for understanding the Fixed Address is a list of pre-qualified addresses the user selects from.

My problem is that I am not understanding something in the articles because my efforts are still resulting in records being entered in two tables.

My most recent attempts went along these lines from one of the articles to get use an object that is a replica / copy of the existing record. (My poor assumption was that EF would recognize there is an existing record and not create a new one)

I don't *KNOW* this to be a part of the problem but I do wonder if my mapping is incorrect so here it is for the CustomerMap:

```
this.HasMany<FixedAddress>(ef => ef.FixedAddress)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m => m.ToTable("Customer_FixedAddress")
    .MapLeftKey("Customer_Id").MapRightKey("FixedAddress_Id"));
```

So basically here is what I do:

```
//This line passes the id of user selected address record to our address service
//which returns an object that is exactly the record I want the relationship pointing to
FixedAddress FxdAddy = _addyService.GetFixedAddressesById(model.FixedAddyId);

//So here I am adding the addy record to the customer object
customer.FixedAddresses.Add(FxdAddy);
```

The result is my Customer table is untouched.
My FixedAddress table has a new record inserted....that is a dupe of the existing record the user selected.

My CustomerFixedAddress table has a new entry that is correct and incorrect. The customerid column is correctly populated. The fixedaddress column is correctly populated with the id of the ***NEW*** dupe record that was inserted.

That is not what I want. The only table that should have a record inserted is CustomerFixedAddress table...and obviously the new record would have the proper customerid and fixedaddressid of the ***EXISTING*** records in the respective tables.

So I kinda understand how the dupe is added to the fixedaddy table...I've added it to the customer object and then ef updates everything from that perspective...but I don't know how to do it differently to get the result I want???

Thank You

---

@slauma this project was developed by people far more knowledgeable so my apologies for hacking through it.

In the addy service I just fire off some LINQ as such:

```
public FixedAddress GetFixedAddressesById(int FxdAddyId)
{
  FixedAddress FxdAddy = new FixedAddress();

  var query = _addressFixedAddressRepository.Table
            .Where(efb => efb.Id == FxdAddyId)
            .Select(...removed save space);
        foreach (var item in query)
        {...removed save space }

        return FxdAddy;
 }
```

Now I think the follow up would be what context is that _addressFixedAddressRepository?

It is defined class wide as:

```
private readonly IRepository<FixedAddress> _addressFixedAddressRepository;
```

and brought into existence in the constructor where it gets passed in then assigned locally.....so is the customer object.

Could it be that I should update the customer object in the addyservice? I say this just guessing that the customer object is in a different context when accessed from the controller..(what I am doing now) thus the return from the service is different in it's eyes.

---

Ok so further I found in the service the

```
private readonly IDbContext _context;
```

and of course it is injected on the constructor.

Comment: In your _addyService.GetFixedAddressesById method are you using the same context or a different context as is monitoring the customer instance? From what you are seeing, I suspect it is a different context, thus the customer context doesn't know you fetched it and needs to add it again.

Comment: I was just fumbling around looking along those lines...although you put it far more succinctly than I.

Comment: You misunderstood @JimWooley's comment. In `_addyService` you load the address, maybe with `context.FixedAddresses.Find(addyId)`. And somewhere you load the `customer`, maybe with `context.Customers.Find(customerId)`. Do those two `context` variables point to the *same context instance*? If not, that duplication happens, and you must change your code somehow to ensure  that the contexts are the same.

Comment: Ohhh undoubtedly I misunderstood. Thank You for chiming in with clarification. Now I have a better idea of what to look for.

Comment: Omg, I see, you are alone with a repository/service architecture monster that you didn't develop yourself :( I think you must grab another level deeper and look where you can see the EF context inside the repository implementation. Main question is then: Is there some `...new MyContext()` inside the repo (=wrong architecture) or is it passed in as parameter (into the constructor for example). If yes, where is the `...new` for the context? Or does the project use an IOC container for the context? Etc....etc.... questions over questions...

Comment: It's interesting...upon further looking I see the dbcontext injected on the constructor for the service but not the controller. Added more of what I found above.

Answer (score 1):

First I want to thank Jim Wooley and Slauma. You were most helpful in getting me started in the right direction. From your comments I was able to better refine my Google searches. For example Slauma stated it was a repository/service architecture. Well from that I had better Google search terms and knew what to read up on and thus resolved the issue.

Secondly my apologies for not providing a technical explanation. I am going to tell others what I did differently but admittedly I still don't understand fully what / how EF is executing under the covers so this answer is my rough draft understanding.

I'll repeat the scenario but for the implementation look at the OP. I had two tables and then a mapping table for them. For example a customer table, and a fixedaddress table. The mapping table brought customer and fixedaddress together.

In the past I had done this by creating an address object and adding it to context. This was fine because the address record needed to be added to the address table AS WELL AS a mapping  entry in the customeraddress table.

However in the case I didn't want an entry in the fixedaddress table yet I was getting one anyway.

What I ended up doing was adding an ID column to my mapping table. I created an entity representation of the mapping table...NOTE the need for a property holding the object to be mapped.

```
public virtual int CustomerId { get; set; }
public virtual int FixedAddressId { get; set; }
public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; } //note this property is NOT in the DB
public virtual FixedAddress FixedAddress { get; set; } //note this property is NOT in the DB
```

I then also changed my mapping as such:

```
this.ToTable("Customer_FixedAddress");
this.HasKey(pc => pc.Id);

this.HasRequired(pc => pc.Customer)
.WithMany(p => p.FixedAddress) //this is an ICollection on the customer object
.HasForeignKey(pc => pc.CustomerId);

this.HasRequired(pc => pc.FixedAddress)
.WithMany()
.HasForeignKey(pc => pc.FixedAddressId);
```

Of course I had to do some clean-up of the code in the service and controller with these changes but once I was done the records inserted properly and all is well.

Thank You again for your help.